# Kusto.Explorer requires secondary account to access azure Log Analytics workspace

Tags: kql, kustomize, kustomer

I am having a challenge accessing azure LA/AI workspace with desktop Kusto.Exploer. I cannot use RUNAS to invoke my secondary account with credentials, accessing workspace in azure. Note that I am able to do that using dataexplorer.azure.com ( since i am already logged into azure portal). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Kusto Explorer allows sign in form within the Client itself – using the Connections toolbar : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer#connections-tab

You can –

1. Click on ‘Sign-Out from AAD’
2. Add your cluster again, and now you'll be prompted to Sign In where you can use the creds from your other User Account.

Comment: Hi ; thank you , the issue is that my AAD credentials are different then my kusto.explorer (exe) on the desktop. Thus, i connect to the Kusto cluster, but i am denied access since  Kusto.explorer is sending my desktop creds , not the secondary account..
thank you again for helping out..

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you are logging to the Log Analytics namespace from a different tenant, you can specify it in the cluster connection "advanced connection string" settings and add at the end the applicable tenant guid using the following ";authority id = tenant Guid" syntax, for example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is more on my primary credentials on my desktop vs my secondary credentials on my Azure portal.  Since i am using my kusto.explorer desktop , that takes by default my primary account creds. The connection string is ok per your comments, but the Azure kusto is denying access since I need to use the secondary account.

Comment: Usually the primary and secondary accounts are the same user just a different AAD tenant (many companies create a new tenant in Azure). If your user name is the same for the primary and secondary this means that the solution I proposed will work. One other way to work around it is to give your other account permission in the Azure Data Explorer database/s, this means that both of your identities will have access to the database. If this is the approach you want to take, go to the portal with the identity that has access and give the other identity permission using the permissions tab

Comment: Thanks Avnera:
I have the condition that my_cred(laptop) is not the same as my_cred(Azure_AAD). I will try to follow your workaround.. thanks again and looking forward to working with you in future..